# Copy one database to another removing repetition of row

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I have a database named "ovhidhan_e_word" and it has a table named `Table1` which contains repetition of rows.But i want to copy that `Table1` into another table named `dic` under another database named "ovidhan".But this time i don't want the repetition of rows.I used this code:

```
  string english_w = "";

        SqlConnection mssql_con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Imon-Bayazid\Documents\ovhidhan_e_word.mdf;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
        SqlConnection con2 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Imon-Bayazid\Documents\ovidhan.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");

        mssql_con.Open();

        SqlCommand mssql_cmnd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT * from Table1", mssql_con);

        SqlDataReader rd = mssql_cmnd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rd.Read())
        {
            english_w = rd.GetString(0);

            con2.Open();

            SqlCommand cmnd2 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("select * from dic where english=@h",con2);
            cmnd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@h",english_w);

            SqlDataReader r = cmnd2.ExecuteReader();
            if (r.Read())
            { }
               else {
                    SqlCommand c = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("insert into dic values(@k)", con2); ;
                    c.Parameters.AddWithValue("@k", english_w);
                    c.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 }

            con2.Close();      
        }

        mssql_con.Close();
```

But it shows the exception **"There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."** on the line "*c.ExecuteNonQuery();*"

How can i solve this???
Another question how can i remove the repetition of rows from a table in mssql??

Comment: where do you get the error? mssql_cmnd has no ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: I think this exception because of SqlDataReader r which is open() but not close(), close it after else statement and also close() the SqlDataReader rd after while statement.

Answer (score 0):

That's because mssql_cmnd is the same SQLCommand you used for the first SQLReader. You probably want to call the SQLCommand c:

```
c.Parameters.AddWithValue("@k", english_w);
c.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

As for the repetition, you can always do a SELECT DISTINCT when you read the data. See heading C in the following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187731.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be "c" instead of "mssql_cmnd" and also recommend having "using" statements around your connection, command and datareader objects.

**Edit**

I didn't test the code but tried to refactor it and replaced data reader with execute scalar.

```
        string english_w = string.Empty;
        using (SqlConnection mssql_con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Imon-Bayazid\Documents\ovhidhan_e_word.mdf;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand mssql_cmnd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from Table1", mssql_con))
            {
                mssql_con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader rd = mssql_cmnd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rd.Read())
                    {
                        english_w = rd.GetString(0);
                        using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Imon-Bayazid\Documents\ovidhan.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"))
                        {
                            con2.Open();
                            using (SqlCommand cmnd2 = new SqlCommand("select top 1 * from dic where english=@h", con2))
                            {
                                cmnd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@h", english_w);
                                object obj = cmnd2.ExecuteScalar();
                                if (obj == null)
                                {
                                    using (SqlCommand c = new SqlCommand("insert into dic values(@k)", con2))
                                    {
                                        c.Parameters.AddWithValue("@k", english_w);
                                        c.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            con2.Close();
                        }
                    }
                    rd.Close();
                }
            }
            mssql_con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from' on the line "object obj = cmnd2.ExecuteScalar();"

Comment: @meo, modified the code. It should be "select top 1 * from" instead of "select top 1 from". Try to debug the code step by step and post any errors occurred.

Answer (score 0):

where do you get the error? `mssql_cmnd` has no `ExecuteNonQuery()` If it is `c`,  try `c.Dispose()` after `c.ExecuteNonQuery()`. Try this to remove duplicate rows

```
select * from table1 h1 where H1.ID in (select max(id) from table1 group by duplicate_row_id);
```

Comment: What error did you get? Also to remove duplicate rows use this SQL. select * from table1 h1 
where H1.ID in (select max(id) from table1 group by duplicate_row_id);